# What commands does salt execute under the hood to achieve desired minion states?

Tags: salt-stack

Rightfully or wrongly, I am assuming that in order to achieve the declarative config defined in the `*.sls` files the salt master must execute a sequence of imperative commands on each minion. E.g., for something like

```
install_docker_1703:
  pkgrepo.managed:
    - humanname: Docker CE Repository
    - name: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
    - key_url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
    - require_in:
      - pkg: docker-ce
  pkg.installed:
    - name: docker-ce
    - hold: True
    - refresh: True
    - cache_valid_time: 30 # very low value for testing purposes
    - version: '17.03.2*'
```

the sequence of these commands is executed

```
add-apt-repository <docker-repo>
apt-get update
apt-get install docker-ce=17.03.2-xxxxxxx
```

plus some checks to verify and compare the current state to the desired one.

I am having trouble debugging the behavior of salt. In the context of the above example, I'm having trouble verifying, whether the apt cache is updated every time I run the salt master (`salt '*' state.apply`), or no more frequently than every 30 seconds, or not at all.

**How can I output to `stdout` (or find in some logfile) the exact sequence of commands executed, plus their respective outputs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find detailed command on the minion in the `/var/log/salt/minion` file,
Most likely you will need to adjust logging level to `DEBUG`, the `log_level_logfile: debug` should suffice. Otherwise you will find errors/warns only.

Debugging the behavior: it's best to checkout the salt sources and find by yourself.
There are simply far too many branches of execution given different conditions salt minion works in.

Each state (state module) consists of multiple module calls (execution modules). In the execution modules you will find the commands. This is the easiest way of determining what are the exact commands for given state

Comment: Thanks, +1. Is it even valid to assume that at the end of the day salt does what it's asked to by executing a series of shell commands?

Comment: Under the hood, depending on the state it just executes the regular commands. Of course some states may not translate to 'commands' but to API calls etc. so keep that in mind